# Некорректная работа input type="number" в ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть форма, в которой присутствует следующий input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="TaxRatio" class="col-md-12">Налоговый коэффициент</label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <input asp-for="TaxRatio" step="0.01" min="0" type="number" 
                class="form-control form-control-line">
    </div>
</div>
```

И также ViewModel, которая сохраняет в себе значения этой формы

```
public double TaxRatio { get; set; }
```

Суть проблемы: при вводе в форму дробных значений в модель приходит 0 (как с разделителем точкой, так и запятой).
Однако при вводе целочисленных значений - все работает корректно.
Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Удалите `value="@Model.TaxRatio"`, это не нужно у вас уже есть `asp-for="TaxRatio"`

Comment: Замечание верное, спасибо, но проблемы не решило(

Comment: Нашел решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658246/asp-net-core-razor-decimal-in-form-value-not-valid
Видимо пока что это единственный способ